# How can one select multiple methods in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I select multiple methods like in the example below?

[image: Successful selection]

The gif is from [CppHelper](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=amiralizadeh9480.cpp-helper) extension.

When I try to select them with `ctrl` and `left click`, VS Code tries to find references instead of selecting them. Here is my attempt:

[image: Selecting items with ctrl + left click]

I also tried selecting mutliple lines with `ctrl` + `L` shortcut but no luck:

[image: Selecting lines with ctrl + L]

Should I install some extension that can do this or is this some in-built feature that I am missing?

Comment: this is called `multiple cursor`, see vsc docs about this https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_multiple-selections-multicursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When clicking, hold down `Alt`, not `Ctrl`.

Comment: Just to point out a small detail, I realized you also have to double click on the name of the method.

Comment: Depends on how the extension works - if it only needs the cursor to point to an identifier, it shouldn't need that. Otherwise, you can use Smart Select Grow to select a whole word (might not always work, e.g. if you have `someWord` and `someOtherWord` because it tries to select sub-words first).